# Create deep copy of twig variable

Tags: templating, craft4, plugin-sprig

I'm building a filter page with Craft and Sprig.
The goal is to show the amount of products for each filter.
So for example if we want to filter on color we show 2 checkboxes "Red" and "Green" and I want to show the number of related products for the Red items and the related number for the green number.

The problem I'm currently encountering is that I calculate the amount of results by adding a `andRelatedTo` parameter to my main query. This works perfect for the first checkbox but since the second checkbox adds another `andRelatedTo` parameter and the previous one is still there the number will always be 0 because none of the products are both "Red" and "Green".

Is there a way to create a deep copy of the original main query so I can reuse it without polluting it with the count of the available options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`clone`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#clone) function makes it possible to clone a query for multiple use.

```
{% set query = craft.products() %}
{% set products = clone(query).andRelatedTo(colours) %}
```

That answers the question, although I’m not sure it solves the underlying issue. If you want to check for *any* related colours, then I’d suggest passing an array into `andRelatedTo`.

Comment: @Matthias Keep a close eye on your query count/performance with this approach, as you're going to be making separate queries for every checkbox. If you end up with lots of filters the performance will suffer. Consider using a look-up table/hash map with all the values you want.

Comment: @JamesSmith That's a valid remark. Do you have any references on how to do this?